# How to hide everything except Application Menu Button in WPF Ribbon?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

When I add a Ribbon in WPF I get a full ribbon control. How can I hide everything except the Application Menu Button? I can do workarounds but is there any standard way to hide other panels?

[image]

I am too lazy to design my own control for this

Answer (score 0):

You can clear items and set ribbon height property to 45 in `Loaded` event.

```
   <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Loaded="Ribbon_Loaded">
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                  x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                  ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                          Header="Home">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                Header="Group1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                     LargeImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"
                                     Label="Button1" />

                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button2"
                                     SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png"
                                     Label="Button2" />
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button3"
                                     SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png"
                                     Label="Button3" />
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button4"
                                     SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png"
                                     Label="Button4" />                    
            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>                
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Code-behind:

```
private void Ribbon_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Ribbon menu = sender as Ribbon;
    menu.Height = 45;
    menu.Items.Clear();
}
```

You can use it separate outside ribbon control but in this case you will lose style in drop down menu:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                  x:Name="MenuItem9"
                                                  ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"                                              
                                          />
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>

</Grid>                                     
                                          />
    </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
```

Comment: As I said, I know I can do workarounds but is there any standard way?

Comment: @HarisHasan I think that it's standard way, if you try use it outside of ribbon control you will lose style of drop down menu, so if you want exactly the same behaviour as inside ribbon control you should use my solution.